# How to resolve linker error: undefined symbol - C++

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I'm getting the same linker error when trying to run code:
`ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: Serialize::Archive& Serialize::Archive::operator>><double>(double&)`

main.cpp (snippets):

```
using namespace Serialize;
Archive arc(file, Archive::Save_Archive);
    
    double test;
    std::cout<<"Enter some data: ";
    std::cin >> test;
    arc >> test;
```

Archive.hpp:

```
namespace Serialize{
template<typename T>
    Archive& operator>>(T& obj); 
}
```

Archive.cpp:

```
namespace Serialize{
template<typename T>
    Archive& Archive::operator>>(T& obj){};
}
```

I don't believe I have any namespace issues and the operator is only defined and declared once in the hpp and cpp files.

I tried switching around using namespace Serialize and namespace Serialize and even just doing

```
Serialize::Archive arc(file, Serialize::Archive::Save_Archive);
```

Comment: @Nathan Heffington Move the definition of the template operator in the header. The compiler is unable to instantiate the operator when it compiles the module with main.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file